# How to update a value of a nested object in a reducer?

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have built my state like so

```
const list = {
  categories: {
   Professional: {
    active: false,
    names: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Golf",
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ultimate Frisbee",
        active: false
      }
  ] 
}}
```

In my action I have added an ID option so I would like to change the active status when the user clicks the option to do so

I am using Immutable JS though not married to it. I am wondering how I could target the id of the object and update its active status in a reducer? I am also open to feedback on how to better improve my state

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This is very common thing, and, actually, quite daunting. As far as I know, there is no really good and well-adopted solution in plain JS. Initially, `Object.assign` approach was used:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  categories: Object.assign({}, state.categories, {
    Professional: Object.assign({}, state.Professional, {
      active: true
    })
  })
});
```

This is too straightforward and cumbersome, I admit it, but I have to say that we've built few big applications with this approaches, and except for number of characters it is not bad. Nowadays, the most popular approach is using [Object spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/):

```
return {
  ...state,
  categories: {
    ...state.categories,
    Professional: {
      ...state.categories.Professional,
      active: true
    }
  }
}
```

The second approach is much more cleaner, so if you use plain JS, then it seems as a good choice.
In Immutable.js I have to admit it is easier, you just do the next

```
return state.updateIn(['categories', 'Professional'], x => x.set('active', true));
```

But it has it's own drawbacks and caveats, so it is better to think about it seriously before committing to it.

And your last question regarding improving the state – usually it is better not to have such deep nesting (separate your concerns, very often fields don't depend on each other – like `active` status can be separated to another object), but it is hard to say because of no knowledge of your domain. Also, it is considered as normal thing to [normalize](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) your data.

Comment: well said, well exampled, well referenced. +1

Answer (score 13):

The Redux docs section on [Structuring Reducers](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers) covers this.  In particular, see the section on [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/).  The examples given are for plain JS objects and arrays, but the same approach applies - `map()` over the list, return the existing item for everything you *don't* want to update and return a new version for the one you *do* want to update.

Per the docs, also note that it's easier to update a specific item if your data is stored in a normalized structure, since you can look it up by ID directly.  The "Structuring Reducers" section covers normalization as well.