# How can I update 1 property of object in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reduxreducer which looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    visitedData:{specialty:false,review:false,reviewUpgrade:false}
}

const myred= (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GO_FOR_IT_SON':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { visitedData: action.data });

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Now from my reactcomponent I will call something like:

```
 store.dispatch({type: 'GO_FOR_IT_SON', data:{review:true} });
```

or:

```
 store.dispatch({type: 'GO_FOR_IT_SON', data:{specialty:false} });
```

So each of these statements are supposed to set one of the properties of visitedData to true/false and leaving the other ones intact.
How can I set each of the properties of visitedData to true/false and leaving the other properties unchanged?

Comment: What do you mean by How can I set each of the properties of visitedData to true/false and leaving the other properties unchanged? Do you want to change multiple properties at the same time? Or do you want to change visitedData properties without changing other state properties?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096036/how-to-update-a-value-of-a-nested-object-in-a-reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const initialState = {
      visitedData: {
      specialty: false,
      review: false,
      reviewUpgrade: false
    }
}

const myred = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GO_FOR_IT_SON':
            return {...state, visitedData: {...state.visitedData, action.data}}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

as you did with state - Object.assign, you should do the same with visitedData object or use spread operator instead object.assign

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a reducer and action for every changable property:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const specialty = (state = false, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'TOGGLE_SPECIALTY') {
    return action.data;
  }
  return state;
};

const review = (state = false, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'TOGGLE_REVIEW') {
    return action.data;
  }
  return state;
};

const myred = combineReducers({
  specialty,
  review
});
```

But in your situation, the solution would be:

```
const myred= (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GO_FOR_IT_SON':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visitedData: Object.assign({}, state.visitedData, action.data)
      });

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: No it was not. Look more closely to the `Object.assign`. There are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
   visitedData: Object.assign({}, state.visitedData, action.data)
});
```

Check this example:

```js
let a = {b: {a : 1, b : 2, c : 5} };
let b = {a : 5};

let k = Object.assign({}, a, {b: Object.assign({}, a.b, b)});

console.log(k);
```

Comment: You're missing the outer state object; reducers need to return an updated version of the state argument, not a subset of it.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand ya you are right, updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Same as other solution. I suggest to separate object merging into another line and use object spread for more readable

```
const myred = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GO_FOR_IT_SON':
      let newVisitedData = {
        ...state.visitedData,
        ...action.data
      }
      return { visitedData: newVisitedData }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A straight forward brute force ways:

Edit use lodash cloneDeep

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let newState = _.cloneDeep(state)

for(let key in action) {
    newState.visitedData[key] = action[key]
}
```

Comment: This mutates the state.