# How to use variable in spread while updating a value of a nested object in a reducer?

Tags: redux, ngrx-store

My question is just one step ahead of [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096036/how-to-update-a-value-of-a-nested-object-in-a-reducer)

I want to know if there is any way by which I can use variables in place of "Professional" (which is a key in reference question) because my model is of the following type:

```
const list = {
  categories: {
    1: {
      name: "Golf",
      active: false
    },
    2: {
      name: "Ultimate Frisbee",
      active: false
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access 1 and 2 i.e. ids in the code below:

```
return {
  ...state,
  categories: {
    ...state.categories,
    <dynamic_Id>: {
      name:"xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

My main aim is to update name property of selected id.
Please let me know if there is any solution to it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what do you mean

Comment: Where is Professional?

Comment: Please check now and let me know if you need any more info, my question is related to the question asked in the link I provided

Comment: in your state `categories` is an array, yet you attempt to use it as an `object` in your `reducer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after

```
  return {
      ...state,
      categories: {
        ...state.categories,
        [idProp]: {
        ...state.categories[idProp],
          name:"xyz"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is 'idProp' over here?

Comment: I got it. 'idProp' is a variable in which the id that is to be changed is assigned. The main thing here is the syntax which I was not able to find. That square brackets [] are necessary. that solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So Finally My solution is as follows:

```
let idProp = 1;
return {
      ...state,
      categories: {
        ...state.categories,
        [idProp]: {
        ...state.categories[idProp],
          name:"xyz"
        }
      }
    }
```