# Problems achieving required result of using the spread (...) operator with state object

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, ecmascript-6

I have a pimRegistration state initialization as shown in the chrome redux-devtools screen capture below. The nesting being referenced is `pimRegistration` (`state.domain.patient`):

[image]

I updated the `patient.name` object with the following spread operator statement:

```
store.update((state) => ({
  ...state,
  ...patientPath,
  ...{ [property]: value },
}));
```

...where `property` is the "name" property of the patient object with `value`. After the update, the following screenshot shows the new state:

[image: New updated state - yellow colour in screenshot]

Note that the original patient object (purple in the screenshot) is updated with the name object, duplicated and placed at the root of the state (yellow in screenshot).

I would like to overwrite the properties of the `pimRegistration(state).domain.patient` object, *not* to create a new patient object.

The state update is called as shown below.

```
store.update((state) => ({
  ...state,
  ...patientPath, // state.domain.patient
  ...{ [property]: value },
}));
```

I have tried my different combinations without achieving the desired result.

---

The complete update function is shown below.

```
update(property: string, path: string, value: any) {
  const paths: string[] = path.split(".");

  const pathReducer = (state: IRegistrationState, path_: string) => {
    if (paths.length <= 0) {
      return state.domain;
    }
    return state[path_];
  };

  const domainPath = state.domain;
  let patientPath, nokPath, referrerPath;

  if (path.includes("patient")) {
    patientPath = paths.reduce(pathReducer, state);
  }

  if (path.includes("nok")) {
    nokPath = paths.reduce(pathReducer, state);
  }

  if (path.includes("referrer")) {
    referrerPath = paths.reduce(pathReducer, state);
  }

  store.update((state) => ({
    ...state,
    ...patientPath,
    ...{ [property]: value },
  }));
}
```

The function above is invoked with the following statement in Angular 2.

```
if (this.path.includes("patient")) {
  this._repo.update("name", "domain.patient", this.name);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `patientPath`? You may be treating object spreading as if it merged properties. It does _not_ merge recursively.

Comment: I updated/appended the question to show the complete state updater function and function invokation above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep updates to a store can be tricky. In your function you seem to be spreading the updates at the root rather than at the level you want the update at. [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40109764/1231844) outlines the usual practice to update the state. In short, something like

```
const newState = {
  ...state,
  domain: {
    ...state.domain,
    patient: {
      ...state.domain.patient,
      [property]: value
    }
  }
}
```

Dynamically passing a path and updating this state can be… cumbersome. There are libraries that can help you do it such as [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), but you can possibly hack your way around with normal JS/TS.

Comment: As far as I remember, in redux it's also possible to split the state into different sub-states and and have a reducer per a sub-state. These portions can then be merged into single object.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo that's true. I'm not sure if OP is open to refactoring into pseudo-slices, but that's certainly an option.